# How to transfer a Team Foundation Server installation to another server

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio

I have a single server installation of Team Foundation Server 2008.  This means that the Application Tier and Data Tier are on the same server.

I want to move the installation from the old server to the new server.  Could someone please provide me clear steps on how to move the installation from the old server to the new server?

**EDIT:**
This link might also be helpful. It describes the different types of server installation moves and the different steps one might take. [Team Foundation Server Move Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms404860.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN covers this: [How to: Restore Data for Team Foundation Server to a Different Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms252516.aspx). Related sections also cover backup...

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with this at length several months ago in an attempt to create a TFS 2008 "integration server" with all the same data / Team Projects / SharePoint sites as our production one.  I was never successful in this endeavor but never saw the link posted here from MSDN.  Were you successful in this migration?